# Android Get Data from Database from an intent value

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Im so new to this android development. What im trying to do is to pass the id from `MainActivity` to `Details`. So i need to get the id from the `MainActivity` in order to display the details of a person in `Details` class. I can pass the id already and display it, but im having trouble on displaying the details of that specific id which is from the database values. How can i display the contents of that specific id in the `Details` class using the Database function `getDetails(id);` ? I need to display it on the textviews of the `Details` activity class. Please help

DB Function

```
public Cursor getDetails(String id) {
            return database.query(TABLENAME, null, id + "=" + id, null, null,
                    null, null);
        }
```

MainActivity.java

```
this.listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long arg3){

                        TextView txtID = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id);

                        String id = txtID.getText().toString();

                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Details.class);
                        intent.putExtra("id", id);

                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
```

In `Details.java`, i want to display here the contents of the ID which is on the database. How can i call on to that function and make it display using the ID from the intent being passed?

Details.java

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String id = i.getStringExtra("id");

txtId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id);
txtName= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
txtAbout = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.about);

txtId.setText(id);
txtName.setText(name);
txtAbout .setText(about);
```

Comment: In the same way as `id` would be not from intent

Comment: I don't understand - you don't call `getDetails()` anywhere?

Comment: @PPartisan  I want to call getDetails() in Details.java but i dont know how should i put it.

Comment: @Jah I don't think there's enough information here to properly answer the question. The third argument of your `query()` especially doesn't look correct. Posting your DataBase class may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public HashMap<String,String> getDetails(String id) {
    HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.query(TABLENAME, null, "id=?", new String[]{id}, null, null, null);
    if(c.getCount()>0){
      c.moveToFirst();
      hm.put(KEY, c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME)));
    // do this for all columns that you want.
    }
    c.close();
    db.close();
    return hm;
 }
```

and in Details.java

```
String id = getIntent().getExtras.getString("id");
HashMap<String, String> hm = (Your database class Object).getDetails(id);
if(hm.size()>0){
  String value1 = hm.get(KEY);
// get all data and show according to you.
}
```